# Is there an instrument combination of a guitar and a harp?

Tags: guitar, instruments, harp

I wonder whether there is guitar that is extended with strings like a harp - or otherwise a harp that has inbuilt a neck with frets with guitar strings. Does this instrument exist already and how would you call it?

Answer (score 1):

This instrument exists and is called:

**HARP-GUITAR**

Comment: You'll find more if you don't require it to be labelled "harp." https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=metheny+picasso+guitar